# Pandas Styling using conditionals

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to color table cells dependent on values in another column.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':[1.5,3,6],'c':[2.2,2.9,3.5]})
df

    a   b   c
0   1   1.5 2.2
1   2   3.0 2.9
2   3   6.0 3.5
```

For example, in the above df I want b colored red if c>b. So the cell df[0,b] would be highlighted, but none of the others.

I have made multiple attempts, but in general what I have looks like the below

```
def highlight(val1,val2):
    color = 'red' if val1 < val2 else 'black'
    return 'color: %s' % color

df.style.apply(lambda x: highlight(x.data.b,x.data.c), axis = 1,subset=['b'])

TypeError: ('memoryview: invalid slice key', 'occurred at index 0')
```

I do not see any examples in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html).  They are generally using conditionals on a single column such as highlighting a max or min within a column or the entire df.

Maybe what I want is not currently possible?  From the documentation:

> Only label-based slicing is supported right now, not positional.
>
> If your style function uses a subset or axis keyword argument,
>   consider wrapping your function in a functools.partial, partialing out
>   that keyword.

Comment: um, why are you using `x.data`? That returns a `memoryview` object...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need return DataFrame of colors for set styles. So need create new df with same index and columns with default values - here `background-color: red` and then change values by condition:

```
def highlight(x):
    c1 = 'background-color: red'
    c2 = 'background-color: black' 
    #if want set no default colors 
    #c2 = ''  
    m = x['c'] > x['b'] 
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(c2, index=x.index, columns=x.columns)
    df1.loc[m, 'b'] = c1
    return df1

df.style.apply(highlight, axis=None)
```

[image: one]

[image: two]

Comment: i really like this answer. Styling can be difficult. Could you dive deeper into what `c2` is doing in `df1=...`? are you loading ...colors...? as a dateframe?

Comment: Yes, you need return `DataFrame of colors` for set styles. So need create new `df` with same index and columns with default values - here `c2` and then change values by condition.

Comment: FYI `c2 = 'background-color: white'` returns the same transparent result

Comment: @jezrael **"The styling is accomplished using CSS. You write “style functions” that take scalars, DataFrames or Series, and return like-indexed DataFrames or Series with CSS "attribute: value" pairs for the values. "**  I didn't make the connection, until your comment, `DataFrame of colors`.